# Barclays SOAP BPF Integration DTD not supported

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am working on creating an interface to deal with Barclays finance SOAP interface. I have the WSDL and it is valid so I can run both

```
$soapClient->__getTypes()
$soapClient->__getFunctions()
```

which return valid data.

When I try to request a call for example:

```
var_dump($soapClient->__soapCall("SubmitNewApplicationShort", array()));
```

I am getting the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] DTD are not supported by SOAP in  
/www/vhosts/geniusdev.1anetworks.net/http/Barclays/financeWSDL.php:16
Stack trace:
```

I thought this may have been because of the input data but when I have changed it to empty I still do not get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own issue I had added a try and catch on the soap call:

```
try {
    var_dump($soapClient->__soapCall("SubmitNewApplicationShort", array());
} catch ( SoapFault $e ) { // Do NOT try and catch "Exception" here
    var_dump($soapClient->__getLastRequest());
    var_dump($soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders());
    var_dump($soapClient->__getLastResponse());
    var_dump($soapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders());
}
```

Which showed me that it was trying to connect to the localhost rather than the web service. By passing location into the SoapClient declaration it fixed that issue.